# My function is not returning after the if statement

Tags: javascript

So here is my code

```
function balancedBrackets(string) {
  let splited = string.split("");
  let stack = [];
  splited.forEach((x)=>{
    if(x=== '('|| x === '[' || x==='{'){
      stack.push(x)
    } else if( x=== ')'|| x === ']' || x==='}'){
     if((x === ')' && stack[stack.length - 1]!='(') || (x === ']' && stack[stack.length - 1]!='[') ||  (x === '{' && stack[stack.length - 1]!='}') || (stack.lenght===0)){
      return false
     }  else {
       stack.pop();
      }
    }
    
    });
  return stack.length === 0
}
```

It's a function to find if the string of brackets is balanced, and it works partially but when you just imput a closing bracket as the only argument is returns true when it should be returning false as its specified in the if statemen after the else if

Comment: Your `return false` statement is inside the `forEach` callback, so it won't return anything in the wrapping function. A `for` loop would work, instead of a `forEach`

Comment: typo error `stack.lenght===0`

Comment: @MisterJojo where?

Comment: @JaromandaX at the end of `if((x === ')' && stack[stack.length - 1]!='(') || (x === ']' && stack[stack.length - 1]!='[') ||  (x === '{' && stack[stack.length - 1]!='}') || (stack.lenght===0)){`

Comment: d'oh @MisterJojo - forgot to scroll to the right :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return from `forEach`. Replace it with the normal `for-loop` and it will work.

`forEach` function takes just a function to execute over an array element. It does not care for the return value of the passed function.

This would also work:

```
for(let item in items) {
}
```